# Unable to access methods of multimap iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, multimap

I have no idea what's wrong but I can't acces the methods of the object my iterator is referring to. This is what I have:

```
multimap<long, Note>::iterator notesIT;
notesIT = trackIT->getNoteList().lower_bound(this->curMsr * 1000000);

while(notesIT->first / 1000000 == 1){
    cout << notesIT->first.getStartTime() << endl; // error on this line
    notesIT++;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
error: request for member 'getStartTime' in 'notesIT. std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>::operator-> [with _Tp = std::pair<const long int, Note>]()->std::pair<const long int, Note>::first', which is of non-class type 'const long int'
```

Comment: You want the second so use ->second ...

Comment: Distilled error message: "request for member `getStartTime` ... on non-class type `const long int`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler tells you that

```
notesIT->first.getStartTime()
```

is invalid because you are trying to call `getStartTime()` on an `int`.  Obviously, you meant to call it on a `Node`, so select the second part of the pair the iterator points to (that yields the `Node` part of the iterator):

```
cout << notesIT->second.getStartTime() << endl;
```

Comment: I should have seen that. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps:

```
notesIT->second.getStartTime()
```